# How to copy s3 bucket files in to the Kubernetes running pods?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have multiple files in s3 bucket which I need to copy to one of the running Kubernetes pods under /tmp path .
Need any reliable command or try and tested way to do the same.

Let's say my bucket name "learning" and pod name is "test-5c7cd9c-l6qng"

Answer (score 2):

AWS CLI commands "[aws s3api get-object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html)" or "[aws s3 cp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)" can be used to copy the data onto the Pod from S3. To make these calls [AWS Access Keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html#access-keys-and-secret-access-keys) are required. These keys provide the authentication to call the S3 service. "[aws configure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/index.html)" command can be used to configure the Access Keys in the Pod.

Coming to K8S, an [Init Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) can be used to execute the above command before the actual application container starts. Instead of having the Access Keys directly written into the Pod which is not really safe, [K8S Secrets feature](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) can be used to pass/inject the Access Keys to the Pods.

FYI ... the download can be done programmatically by using the [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) and the [S3Client](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html) Interface for Java.

Comment: Can you give an example of the syntax for using "aws s3 cp" to copy a file onto a kubernetes container?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html#examples) is the link to do the same via CLI.